# What is best solution to generate Word document from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, report

I would like to generate a word document from my ASP.NET application. Currently we show an "Agenda List" which is the agenda information and all items/subjects. This page needs to have the ability to open in word. The agenda page is not static, it's a dynamic list of agenda items pulled from SQL Server.

Any suggestions on the best solution? I'm looking for a quick solution and OpenXML seems to be a bit too time consuming. I'm open to purchasing third party tools.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use the Office OpenXML SDK. For later versions of Office (2007 and above), this is the standard. There are other ways as mentioned in other answers, but OpenXML will give you the greatest level of control over the output.

Here is some documentation to get you started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx

Comment: Thanks!! I'm looking this over now! Help is greatly appreciated! If this seems to time consuming, my alternative may be Aspose.

Answer (score 4):

You can either

1. Let the page generate the document yourself (like RTF format)
2. Save the Word template as XML and add your own placeholder where you fill in the content (I know you said this is time consuming which is true if you do a lot of updates to the template)
3. Used 3rd party tool like Aspose (http://www.aspose.com), it worked very well for me as it does save a lot of time to work with the document through objects in C#.

Answer (score 2):

There are three methods that I have used previously:

1. Use the openXML library to programmatively create a document from scratch.
2. Use Office automation to mail merge data with a Word template. You would create your template first and then use a DataSet to populate the data fields.
3. If your database is SQL Server 2005 or later you can use SSRS to generate documents in a number of formats, including Word, PDF, Excel, and CSV.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any 3rd party controls to create a Word document. From 2007 and onward Word can read html as a word document. You simply save any web page with the "**.doc**" extension and Word will sort it out.

Simply create your web page with whatever formatting you want then save it with a .doc extension.

I used `HttpWebRequest`to call the Url (with parmaters) to my page then used `WebResponse` and `Stream` to get my page into a buffer, then `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` to save it to an actual document. I've then got my own custom function to download the file.

If anyone wants my code let me know

Comment: "If anyone wants my code let me know" in the future, please just add any relevant code to the answer itself. Almost four years later, someone is looking for the code and has no effective way of obtaining it. ([This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8767516/mx313) is looking for you in the C# chatroom)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try our 3rd party [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) library.

Here is a sample C# code how to generate template Word (DOCX) document programmatically and use **[mail merge](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/articles/c-sharp-vb-net-mail-merge)** to import data into it:

```cs
var document = new DocumentModel();

document.Sections.Add(
    new Section(document,
        new Paragraph(document, "Agenda List:"),
        new Paragraph(document,
            new Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "RangeStart:Agendas"),
            new Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "Subject") { CharacterFormat = { Bold = true } },
            new SpecialCharacter(document, SpecialCharacterType.LineBreak),
            new SpecialCharacter(document, SpecialCharacterType.Tab),
            new Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "Description")),
        new Paragraph(document,
            new Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "RangeEnd:Agendas"))));

var agendas = new object[]
{
    new { Subject = "First agenda subject", Description = "First agenda description." },
    new { Subject = "Second agenda subject", Description = "Second agenda description." }
};

document.MailMerge.Execute(agendas, "Agendas");

document.Save("Agendas.docx");
```

You can also easily [save Word document to ASP.NET](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/articles/asp-net-export-to-word-pdf) response stream.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to try our [Elerium Word .Net Writer](http://eleriumsoft.com/Word_NET/WordWriter/Default.aspx) component to generate Word document from ASP.NET page. There is a demo with sourse code that shows how to create new Word document using dinamic datatable:

http://eleriumsoft.com/Word_NET/WordWriter/Demo.aspx

*Disclaimer: I'm a developer at Elerium Software.*