# Word Document folder path within Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, filepath

basically I am using **OpenXML** library, I have created a new folder inside my Visual studio project. I named the project 'myTasks'; I've added few word document templates and using Microsoft.Office package; I am able to manipulate documents as I wish.

The challenge is that I am currently using the full file path ( I right click the document --> Properties --> Copied full Path). It works great locally; however as you know it doesn't work when I deploy it on server because it can't access my Local C Drive..

This is what I am currently using on my local project (It works Locally!).

```
    'Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\ProjectTest\myWork\myTasks\Test.docx")
```

I've tried this way to access the 'myTask' folder but it didn't work!

```
Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open("~/myTasks/Test.docx")
```

**UPDATE:**
Now using the openXML NuGet package:

```
Protected Sub btnmyTaskTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

 

    Dim a = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/myTasks/Test.docx")

    Using doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(a, True)

        Dim document = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document



        Dim savedDoc As WordprocessingDocument = doc.SaveAs("C:\temp2.docx")



        savedDoc.Close()

    End Using



End Sub
```

I've tried playing around with this but to no avail. All your helps are very much Appreciated :)

Comment: I see you've used "~" in the path, which makes me think that you're using ASP.NET, in which case you would need `Server.MapPath("~/myTasks/Test.docx")` instead of just `"~/myTasks/Test.docx"`. *However*, Office is not recommended for use on a web server: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Comment: thank you! I've checked the link, it doesn't give much info to alternatives. I was hoping if my file path is correct my project to work on server as it works well locally and I believe Office is installed on Server! Server.Map path didn't work on my code..

Comment: I assume that you remembered to upload the "myTasks" folder to the server. There are other alternatives suggested in [What is best solution to generate Word document from ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15989686/1115360) Can you confirm that this is ASP.NET? Just saying a server could mean a file server on a LAN.

Comment: I didn't upload the new folder on server. wouldn't be included when I publish it ? And yes I am using ASP.NET application.

Comment: "wouldn't be included when I publish it ?" - I would not assume it would be.

Comment: I did include the folder on the server now but no Luck!!!!

Comment: You may have encountered one of the scenarios in which you cannot use Word and will have to use an alternative (as mentioned in earlier comments).

Comment: The other day I was using Microsoft.Office package but today I've installed openXML nuget package and the code above is using it. I was under the impression OpenXML should work regardless if Office is instaled on server

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that. I would be disappointed if an ASP.NET application could write to the root of the C: drive - it would show that file permissions have been abused. Have you tried saving the file into a subdirectory of the website? E.g. make a folder named "saves", give the IIS_IUSRS account write permission to that folder, and save it to `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/saves/Test.docx")`.

Comment: To be honest, the task is for them to be able to open the word template by clicking the button (and pre-populate certain fields based on the current customer they are viewing) then they can save it themselves. I just could not achieve just opening the file. Do you know how can I by clicking the button open the template pls ?